# how do I execute several programs consecutively in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have a couple of applications that I would like to execute one following the other.

how do I do this?
I tried this but the second task never executed.

```
on error resume next
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\my folder\do task1.exe.vbs"""

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\my folder\do task2.exe.vbs"""

msgbox "Finished tasks"
```

update:
notes found on WshShell.Run [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing (per ISDi's answer) is the third parameter of Run, which tells it to not wait for the program to quit (false), before continuing code exection.

Try (If you want to put your code in a subroutine, which if good coding practice for repeat activities):

```
'Place all of the following in a .vbs file

Sub RunApplication(ByVal sFile)

    Dim WShell : Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WShell.Run Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34), 8, false

End Sub


'Executing apps.

RunApplication "C:\Program Files\my folder\task1.exe"
RunApplication "C:\Program Files\my folder\task2.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

The Run method of WScript.shell has an optional parameter that can halt execution of the script until the Run method returns.

Try:

```
WshShell.Run("""C:\YourPathTo\task1.exe""", 1, true)
```

The third parameter, true in the line above tells the interpreter to wait until this task exits before continuing to the next line of the script.

-isdi-